# Нужна ли запятая перед «да»? Можно ли поставить тире?

Tags: запятые, тире

*«Раньше или позже да найдет».*

1) Нужна ли запятая перед «да»? 2) Можно ли поставить перед «да» тире ради усиления эмоционального посыла — угрозы?

Comment: Запятая точно не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опять же, предложение, в котором постановка того или иного знака полностью зависит от смысла.

1. Если "да" равносильно союзу "и", то запятая не будет ставиться. Перестрою предложение:

**И найдёт раньше или позже.**

В таком случае это предложение имеет связь с предыдущим.

2. Если же "да" равно "но",  то запятая ставится:

**Раньше или позже, но найдёт.**

В таком случае "раньше или позже" выступает (если совсем верно, то они оба это делают, но по отдельности) в качестве обособленного обстоятельства, но в основном ненорматианого, что связано с употреблением только наречий). "Но" здесь относится к предыдущему предложению.

**Примечание**: отмечу, что в этом случае немного нестандартная конструкция предложения, поэтому можно разобрать его по-другому. На мой взгляд, синтаксичкски верным был бы такой вариант:

**Найдёт, но раньше или позже.**

Здесь **найдет, раньше, позже** являются сказуемыми (сразу скажу, что данной информацией владею благодаря чьему-то ответу на этом же форуме). Тогда, если немного подумать, наш вариант может быть примерно таким же, но с другим смыслом. Так, можно сказать, что предложение в какой-то степени неполное. Приведу пример:

**Он найдёт ручку?**

**Раньше или позже (найдёт раньше или позже), но найдёт (можно добавить "обязательно").**

Как видим, смысл несколько изменился.

3. Обособление с использованием тире возможно, но в частной ситуации, для чего я и создал отдельный пункт.

Здесь уже необходимо поставить два знака препинания: тире и запятую. Поясню:

**Раньше или позже — да, найдёт.**

Здесь "да" является положительной частицей, необходимой для ответа на вопрос. Тире ставится благодаря логическому ударению.

Постановка же обычного тире, может быть, возможна, но в том случае, если **частица "да" выступает в качестве восклицательной**. Тогда нужен восклицательный знак. Постановка тире зависит от логического ударения.

Comment: Можно задать вопрос по ответу? Вот такой вариант: Когда-нибудь да найдет. Здесь тоже возможно значение "но" и запятая. В Нацкорпусе запятой вроде бы нет http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&text=lexform&req=когда-нибудь%20да&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&p=1  Тогда какая разница? Вы можете привести примеры с запятой перед ДА?

Comment: Также задам вопрос, чтобы исключить недопонимание. Нацкорпус — ресурс, в котором приведены примеры употребления в каких-либо произведениях достаточно распространенных языковых конструкций? Просто, к сожалению, никогда ничем подобным не пользовался.

Comment: Ну, если в таком известном ресурсе, как Нацкорпус, нет такого примера, то, как мне кажется, найти его будет весьма трудно. А как Вы сами считаете? Возможен ли такой вариант?

Comment: Я когда-то тоже не пользовалась, и это была совсем другая жизнь. Я рассказывала здесь о теории, о своем понимании вопроса, но меня очень любили не слушать (и сейчас-то не слушают, а раньше и подавно).  А тут появились доказательства в виде текстов, и тогда мои позиции значительно упрочились. Сейчас я практически перед каждым ответом туда заглядываю (ошибаться нельзя,  минусуют сразу).

Comment: Собственно, этим я и занимаюсь, создавая ответы, полностью основанные на моём понимании определённой ситуации) Но довольно печально, что простое человеческое мнение стоит ниже формальностей, которые фактически тоже являются мнением определённых людей.

Comment: Собственное понимание требуется на неопределенной территории, которая не контролируется правилами. Когда же вы свое понимание противопоставляете официальным правилам, то это, разумеется, поощряться не будет, да и ценности особой не имеет. Надо уметь работать в рамках закона, это тоже интересно, так как не каждая задача уже решена.Тогда Ваша позиция будет выигрышной. Готовьте защиту, не дожидаясь нападения, а правила это и есть защита.

Comment: С тем, что лучше не идти против правил, я полностью согласен, поскольку есть сообщества людей, занимающихся подобными вопросами более профессионально. Однако, к сожалению, эти правила существуют не для каждого случая. И очень жаль, что такой „нейтральной территории” нет — было бы интересно послушать мнения других.

Comment: Я немного не об этом. Для меня все правила - это Розенталь, ПАС и грамматика, больше ничего не нужно. Ну в Грамоту можно заглянуть, да и то ради интереса (это всего лишь толкование официальных правил). Всё, чего нет у Розенталя, надо решать самим, но решение должно быть основано на грамматике и существующих правилах. "Я так думаю"  - это на крайний случай. Тренироваться же здесь можно каждый день - нестандартных задач много. Так что еще раз желаю Вам удачи.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Собственно, по этому поводу я и решил зарегистрироваться на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

***Раньше или позже да найдет.***

1) Запятая не ставится, ***да*** является частицей.

Из словаря:  **ДА** 8. (в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.). Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности. ***И я чего-нибудь да стою!***

2) Примеры:

Иногда **хоть один гриб да найдет**, а тут ни одного. [В. В. Голявкин. Красные качели (1973)]

Каждый пороется у себя в памяти и непременно **какое-нибудь сеченье да найдет**… [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Мелочи жизни (1886-1887)]

3) В принципе тире возможно при определенном контексте, если делается пауза, например:

*А вдруг всё-таки найдет? **Раньше или позже — да найдет?***