# Необходимость в запятой в следующем предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли поставить запятую?

> Что-нибудь да посоветует.

Comment: А где её тут можно поставить?!

Comment: Дубликат вопроса. Сейчас постараюсь найти соответствующую ссылку

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли запятая перед «да»? Можно ли поставить тире?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452270/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Мне _кажется,_ что у предложений разная структура и вопрос возможно оставить. "Раньше или позже да найдет". А то мы таким образом "поназакрываем" все вопросы, в которых попадается (или обсуждается) частица "да".

Comment: Как мне кажется, предложения довольно сильно идентичны. Если рассуждать по логике, изложенной мной и Sharon в старом вопросе, то она ничем не отличается от данной. Единственным исключением является, пожалуй, большая неполнота, если так можно сказать.

Comment: @БотБотович *довольно сильно идентичны* ))) идентичность - она как беременность. Или она есть - или её нет.

Comment: Да, привели вы сравнение, конечно) Но и с такими деликатными вещами, как pregnancy, тоже бывают сомнения

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении запятая не требуется.

[ДА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B0), **частица.**
**8.** (*в начале предложения или внутри его перед сказуемым, группой сказуемых*). Употребляется для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности.
*И я чего-нибудь **да** стою!*

В словаре Ефремовой:
***Да,*** частица. 7. Употребляется при придании большей силы или выразительности **отдельному слову** или целому высказыванию.

*Вам бы в охранный дом "Васильев и сыновья" обратиться. Глядишь, что-нибудь да посоветуют* (А. Смирнов); *Он нам что-нибудь да посоветует* (Д. Мартин); *Когда вернемся из Англии, обязательно расскажу все монсеньёру, он что-нибудь да посоветует...* (А. Бушков)